# When does this non linear 2 equation system have solutions? What is the solution?

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I need to solve the following system:

$$ \begin{cases} 
a x_0^2 = \exp{ \left( -\dfrac{x_0^2}{4 \sigma^2} \right) } +a r^2 \\
 \exp{ \left( -\dfrac{x_0^2}{4 \sigma^2} \right) } + 4 a \sigma^2 = 0
\end{cases}$$

where the varaibles are $ x_0, a$. You can also take $x_0 >0$

Answer (score 1):

The solution for $|r|\ge 2\sigma$ is

$$ \begin{cases} 
x_0 = \sqrt{r^{2}-4\sigma ^{2}}>0 \\[2ex]
a=-\dfrac{1}{4\sigma ^{2}}\exp \left( -\dfrac{r^2-4\sigma ^{2}}{4\sigma ^{2}}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{4\sigma ^{2}}\exp \left( -\dfrac{x_0^2}{4\sigma ^{2}}\right).
\end{cases}$$

Since $\exp ( -\frac{x_{0}^{2}}{4\sigma ^{2}})>0$,  the second equation implies that $a< 0$. For convenience write

$$E=\exp \left( -\dfrac{x_{0}^{2}}{4\sigma ^{2}}\right).$$

The system is easily solvable, e.g. as follows:

$$ \begin{cases} 
ax_0^2 = E+ar^2 \\[2ex]
E+4a\sigma^2=0
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases} 
ax_0^2 = -4a\sigma^2+ar^2 \\[2ex]
E=-4a\sigma^2
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases} 
x_0^2 = -4\sigma^2+r^2 \\[2ex]
a=-\dfrac{1}{4\sigma ^{2}}E.
\end{cases}
$$